# Why is this Java code not working calculate average max and min?

Tags: java

I am supposed to build a program that gets the grades in a class and calculates min and max and average then ask if you want to continue. This is the code I used but it's still not working. Can you see where the mistake is?

```
public class calculateAvgMAxMin
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); // declares scanner input
        LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>(); // declare new LinkedList of variables which are the grades

        int answer = 1; // declare variable answer =1 
        do { // start of do loop 

            System.out.print("Please enter the name of the course:"); // gives a prompt to enter the name of the course

            // goes to the next line

            String course=input.nextLine(); // declare course as string and sets the value as the input

            System.out.println("Please enter the scores for " + course + " on a single line and type a -1 at the end"); //prompts user to enter scores for class in one line and -1 to stop

            int max=-100; // declare max as integer = -100
            int min=500;//declare min as integer = 500

            int sum=0;// declare sum as intgetr = 0
            int grade;     // declare grade as integer  

            grade=input.nextInt(); // set grade as next user iput

            if (grade==-1) //  if statement if the sentinel value is set then stop
                break;

            list.add(grade); // adds the grade from the grade variable to the LinkedList
            sum=sum+grade;// put the value of sum to sum and the new grade

            if (grade>max) // if statement if grade is more than the max then sets max as the grade
                max=grade;
            if (grade<min) // if statement if grade is less than the min then sets min as the grade
                min=grade;

            System.out.println("The course name: "+ course); // prints message of the course name entered
            System.out.println("Number of Scores :"+list.size()); // sits the number of scores using the size of the list
            System.out.printf("The Average Score: %.2f" ,(double)sum/list.size()); // calculates average to 2 decimal values using the sum divided by the length of the list
            System.out.println(); // goes to next line
            System.out.println("The Minimum Score: "+min); // sets the minimum value to min
            System.out.println("The Maximum Score :"+max);// sets the minimum value to min
            answer = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null," Would you like to continue?"); // sets the value of the variable answer to confrim dialog box
        } while (answer == 0);  // sets the condition for do loop to answer == o so that it would continue only if the yes is selected

    }
}
```

Comment: Because you declare your variables inside the loop. The value resets on each iteration.

Comment: i changed the variables outside the loop but it keeps telling me the number of terms is 1 it doesnt count the input correctly

Comment: Define not working in your question.

Comment: the output number of terms comes out as equal to 1, and so there is only one number calculated as max and min

Answer (score 0):

I think the following lines are incorrect:

```
int max=-100; // declare max as integer = -100
 int min=500;//declare min as integer = 500
```

They should be:

```
int max= 500; // declare max as integer = -100
 int min=-100;//declare min as integer = 500
```

Also they should be moved outside `do-while`.

Comment: unfortunately this is not the issue

Comment: They do need to be moved outside the dowhile @WatsDavies but min should really `Integer.PositiveInfinity` and max `Integer.NegativeInfinity`

Comment: @BenKnoble: OP must have taken these value after some consideration I suppose.

Comment: True. Its a typical max algo; update a value when you find one higher, so it has to start really low

Comment: @BenKnoble: Agree but it is also possible in case of OP that minimum value cannot be less than min selected by him. If we are open to all integer values then it makes sense to go with `Integer.MIN_VALUE`. And we do not have `Integer.NegativeInfinity`?

Comment: My java is a little rusty--i meant min and max value

Answer (score 0):

You need another do..while for each score

```
     int grade;     // declare grade as integer  
     do{
        grade=input.nextInt(); // set grade as next user iput

        if(grade==-1) //  if statement if the sentinel value is set then stop
             break ;

         list.add(grade); // adds the grade from the grade variable to the LinkedList
         sum=sum+grade;// put the value of sum to sum and the new grade

         if(grade>max) // if statement if grade is more than the max then sets max as the grade
             max=grade;
         if(grade<min) // if statement if grade is less than the min then sets min as the grade
             min=grade;
     } while (true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would start by programming to the `List` interface (instead of the concrete collection) and I would prefer the diamond operator `<>` (available Java 7+). Next, I would initialize `max` and `min` to `Integer.MIN_VALUE` and `Integer.MAX_VALUE` respectively (because no `int` is smaller than the first or, it follows, larger than the second). Then I'd prefer `Math.max(int, int)` and `Math.min(int, int)`. Finally, I suggest you get all the values before you display statistics. Something like,

```
List<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>();
int answer = 1;
int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
int sum = 0;
do {
    System.out.print("Please enter the name of the course:");
    String course = input.nextLine();
    System.out.printf("Please enter the scores for %s on a single "
            + "line and type a -1 at the end%n", course);
    int grade = input.nextInt();
    if (grade == -1) {
        break;
    }
    System.out.printf("Course %s, Grade %d%n", course, grade);
    list.add(grade);
    sum += grade;
    max = Math.max(max, grade);
    min = Math.min(min, grade);
    answer = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,
            "Would you like to continue?");
} while (answer == 0);
System.out.println("Number of Scores :" + list.size());
System.out.printf("The Average Score: %.2f%n",
        sum / (double) list.size());
System.out.println("The Minimum Score: " + min);
System.out.println("The Maximum Score :" + max);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an error with where and what you're setting the max and min values to.  It should be:

```
int min = -100;
int max = 500;
```